# Копируется файл в папку с обработчиком

Tags: php

При загрузке на сервер изображения оно, помимо перемещения в папку постоянного хранения, копируется в папку, в которой находится сам обработчик загрузки. Подскажите, как нивелировать сей эффект. Код, относящийся к загрузке файла:

```
$uploaddir = '../images/uploads/directors/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$photoname = 'dir_photo_' . date('U') . '.' 
       . pathinfo($uploadfile,  PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (!is_dir($uploaddir)) {
    mkdir($uploaddir, 0777, true);
}

if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    mysqli_close($db);
    die ('Файл не был загружен');
}

if (!rename($uploadfile, $photoname)) {
    mysqli_close($db);
    die ('Ошибка переименования файла');
}
```

Comment: В этом куске кода нет никакого копирования, есть только перемещение файла. Возможно файл не удается переместить и тогда он остается в папке с обработчиком.
Можно попробовать совместить move_uploaded_file и rename - роль у них одна и таже переместить файл. Вам не нужно перемещаеть его 2 раза.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: я продублировал ниже, как ответ. Пометьте, пожалуйста, мой ответ как верный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом куске кода нет никакого копирования, есть только перемещение файла. Возможно файл не удается переместить и тогда он остается в папке с обработчиком. Можно попробовать совместить move_uploaded_file и rename - роль у них одна и таже переместить файл. Вам не нужно перемещаеть его 2 раза.